# Iterating through tuple and compare index values with items from the list

Tags: python

I have a tuple and list. I need to replace items in the list with values from tuple but on the way that I'm taking item from list comparing it with indexes in tuple and if there is some match I need to take value from tuple and to replace that item in list with that value.

If this is little bit confusing, here is a pseudeocode:

```
tuple = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')

list = ['1','4','8','3','b','g','x','4','z','r','0','0']

result = ['b','e','i','d','b','g','x','e','z','r','a','a']
```

I'm new in Python so I tried to implement some previous knowledge from C#, Java, JS, PHP etc but without success.

**UPDATE: This is solution for my question, thank you people to you all!**

```
input_tuple = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j')
input_list = ['1','2','0','1','3','0','7','9','12','899']

lenght=len(input_tuple)-1 # find last index value in tuple

for i, v in enumerate(input_list):
    #print (i, v)       

    result = [v if not v.isdigit() or int(v)>lenght else input_tuple[int(v)] for v in input_list] #slight modification "or int(v)>lenght" to avoid if number in list is bigger then index of tuple 

print(result)
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried and describe how it failed? If you got an exception, include the full traceback. If you got incorrect results, describe what you got and what you expected.

Comment: You have to try. Post your code, and we can see if there's a specific problem.

Comment: So the elements in `list` are (string versions of) indices into `tuple`, or elements to be added directly to `result`. How, though, does `'0'` in `list` become `'1'` in `result`?

Comment: chepner , elements in list are comming from input and could be a combination of integer and strings. If there is a integer in list it should be replaced with value from tuple that index is same as integer. Result is a new list with integers replaced with values from tuple. 0 in result become '1' because of my mistake :)

Comment: What are the possible values in `list`? (By the way, you should never use special words like `tuple` and `list` for variable names.) Is each item guaranteed to be a string of length `1` holding a decimal digits or English alphabetic character? What should be done if the item is `9` so that there is no corresponding elements in `tuple`? You need to make your requirements more clear, in addition to showing some of your own work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace numeric strings in your list with the corresponding string from the tuple, interpreting the numeric string as an index.

That's not too hard to do:

```
for i, v in enumerate(input_list):
    if v.isdigit():
        input_list[i] = input_tuple[int(v)]
```

Note that this modifies the input list in place. If you don't want to do that, you can instead create a new list with a list comprehension:

```
result = [v if not v.isdigit() else input_tuple[int(v)] for v in input_list]
```

Note that I'm not using your original names `tuple` and `list` because those are the names of the builtin types, and it's a bad idea to mask them (it can cause bugs if you want to call them in other code).

Comment: It was a question of beginner in Python philosophy :) Thank you so much for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'123'.isdigit()` to check whether values is digit or not.

```py
t = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')
l = ['1','4','8','3','b','g','x','4','z','r','0','0']
[list(t)[int(el)] if el.isdigit() else el for el in l]
```

Output:

```
['b', 'e', 'i', 'd', 'b', 'g', 'x', 'e', 'z', 'r', 'a', 'a']
```

Comment: You don’t need list(t): [t[int(el)] if el.isdigit() else el for el in l]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `map()` with some help function. For example:

```
t = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')    
l = ['1','4','8','3','b','g','x','4','z','r','0','0']

def func(x):
    if x.isdigit():
        return  t[int(x)]
    else:
        return x

r = list(map(func, l))
# ['b', 'e', 'i', 'd', 'b', 'g', 'x', 'e', 'z', 'r', 'a', 'a']
```

or listcomp:

```
r = [func(i) for i in l]
```